# Rails form_for ends abruptly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to place a form inside `tr` element like this

```
<%= form_for @meal, html: { class: 'form-inline' }, remote: true do |f| %>
  <td class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Meal' %></td>
  <td class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :calories, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Calories' %></td>
  <td class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :meal_time_text, class: 'form-control time-picker', placeholder: 'Time' %></td>
  <td class="form-group"><%= f.text_field :meal_date_text, class: 'form-control date-picker', placeholder: 'Date' %></td>
  <td>
      <%= f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', default: t("helpers.links.cancel")),
        meals_path, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

But when I do inspect element I see this

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/meals" class="form-inline" data-remote="true" id="new_meal" method="post"></form>
<td class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="meal_name" name="meal[name]" placeholder="Meal" type="text"></td>
.... (rest of the td's)
```

I don't understand whats going on here and how can I fix this?

Comment: Is your `form` working? Why you need a `form` inside `tr`.Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: +1 for @Mandeep's answer. And as it appears you are using Bootstrap, you should rely on Bootstrap's layout rather than using a table-based layout anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you look at [**`tr`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TR) element,  **only th and td elements can be direct contents of tr** and in your code you have form as direct content of tr*

Comment: @BhushanLodha i doubt as if you'll use form tag inside a td you'll have to close td before your form and it'll be invalid html. You'll have to use full form inside a td. You can't have each field inside a td element

Comment: @BhushanLodha you can experiment by doing a table tag inside a td and then use tr but i doubt as it'll also have the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is a bad html dom structure a whole form can be contain inside single `td` or the whole table must be contained inside `form`.

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

## OR

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```